# Различаются отправляемый и получаемый заголовки (Content-type)

Tags: php, mysql, ios

В скрипте пишу `header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');`, а принимающая сторона кричит `Request failed: unacceptable content-type: image/jpeg`...

ps. Запрос делаю через AFNetrowking. Причем с одной и той же таблицы (MySQL) одни данные приходят с корректным заголовком - другие с jpeg...

**ДОБАВЛЕНО**: Скопировал строчку в БД на другую позицию с другим id... и пришел корректный заголовок! Получается что тип заголовка напрямую может как-то зависеть от конкретной строки в MySQL??!

Так же проверял запрос через сервис http://checkmy.ru/?go=checkmy.ru
приходит корректный `Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8`...

Делал запрос саппорту - ответ "Мы отправляем Вас заголовок с JSON"...

Видимо что-то с настройками самого AFNetworking? Как его заставить принимать заголовок JSON?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
```

Answer (score 0):

А в качестве сервера что? Может быть там активирован модуль типа mime_magic, который по первым отправляемым клиенту байтам пытается самостоятельно определить тип mime?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Может кто сталкивался с багом, когда AFNetworking начинает принимаемый заголовок json выдавать за Image/jpeg? 
Еще раз проверил - сервер отдает корректный Json.

Comment: И, заметил, что на симуляторе приходит JSON, а на iPhone - image/jpeg!